# QGIS: Coordinates in graphical modeler

Tags: qgis, coordinates, qgis-modeler

With the graphical modeler in QGIS, how can I get the coordinates from a point layer in input and putting this value in the algorithm [shortest path from vector to point](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html?#shortest-path-layer-to-point) in the related input of the end point coordinates.

I calculated the coordinates of the point with the field calculator algorithm and i used the variable `@calculated_coordinates_OUTPUT` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the point layer itself as second input to the tool?

Comment: @Erik, unfortunately, that particular tool does not accept a layer as the second input, it must be a coordinate pair ( `x,y` ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set input for end point to `Pre-calculated value`, then use this expression:

```
eval (' @end_maxx  || '','' ||  @end_maxy ')
```

[image]